# Dropzone.js getting image for Preview

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to get the real image that is queued in the Dropzone and show a preview, but the only image i can get is the one  of the thumbnail, is there a way to get the real image?

here is my code:

```
 var uploadDrop = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
       acceptedFiles: "image/png",
       url: "${g.createLink(controller:'perfil',action: 'saveFile')}",
        maxFiles: 1, // Number of files at a time
        maxFilesize: 1, //in MB
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        maxfilesexceeded: function(file){
            alert('You have uploaded more than 1 Image. Only the first file will be uploaded!');
        },
        init: function(){
            this.on("addedfile", function() {
                if (this.files[1]!=null){
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }

            });
        },
          thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
            // Display the image in your file.previewElement
            $(file.previewElement).removeClass("dz-file-preview").addClass("dz-image-preview");
            $(file.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src",dataUrl);
            $("#preview").attr("src",dataUrl);
          },
        success: function (response) {
            var x = JSON.parse(response.xhr.responseText);
            var message=x.data.message;
           if (message.pass) {
               originalLogoName=x.data.data.logoName
                      pasoPorSubida=true;
               simpleMessage(message.title, message.body, "success");
            this.removeAllFiles(); // This removes all files after upload to reset dropzone for next upload
           } else {
               simpleMessage(message.title, message.body, "error");
           }
        },
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        removedfile: function(file) {
            var _ref; // Remove file on clicking the 'Remove file' button
            if(!success){
                $("#preview").attr("src",originalLogoUrl+"/"+originalLogoName);
            }else{
                success=false;
            }
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I think the best approach should be to upload the image and then get the url and load the image, if you don't want to upload the image you can take a look at the dropzone options `thumbnailWidth`  and `thumbnailHeight` http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-thumbnailWidth. Setting them to null will not resize the thumbnail but this can create some lag with big images

Comment: @wallek876 thank you for your response, after playing a little with the size of the thumbnail i could get the image i wanted, thanks for your suggestion!!.